# Set width on input mat-form-fields for angular material

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, angular-flex-layout

I am so very new to Angular, and I am trying to create a form with longer-than-default input fields.  This is my current code:

`person.component.html`

```xml
<form class="new-person-form">
    <mat-card>
        <mat-form-field>
            <input matInput placeholder="Name">
        </mat-form-field>
        <mat-form-field>
            <input matInput placeholder="Birthday">
        </mat-form-field>
        <mat-checkbox>Active</mat-checkbox>
    </mat-card>
</form>
```

`person.component.css`

```css
.mat-form-field {
    padding: 10px;
}

.mat-checkbox {
    padding: 10px;
}
```

`person.component.html`

```xml
<form class="new-person-form">
    <mat-card fxLayout="row">
        <mat-form-field>
            <input matInput placeholder="Name" fxFlex="50">
        </mat-form-field>
        <mat-form-field>
            <input matInput placeholder="Birthday" fxFlex="25">
        </mat-form-field>
        <mat-checkbox fxFlex="25">Active</mat-checkbox>
    </mat-card>
</form>
```

`person.component.css`

```css
.mat-form-field {
    padding: 10px;
}

.mat-checkbox {
    padding: 10px;
}
```

And this is the result:

```
|                                                                          |
|   Name___________  Birthday_______  [] Active                            |
|                                                                          |
```

I'm trying to lengthen `Name` to be about 50% of the page, so something like this:

```
|                                                                          |
|   Name___________________________  Birthday_______  [] Active            |
|                                                                          |
```

I'm not super great at CSS, so I think FlexLayout might be what I need, but so far I can't get it to work correctly.

Comment: Did you try the `size` attribute?

Comment: by longer you mean visually longer?

Comment: Yes, visually.  I like the idea of flexlayout, but I can't seem to get it to work.  I'd love to be able to just set a field to take up a certain percentage of the screen and let that be that.

Answer (score 57):

This will change the width of matform field

```
<mat-form-field [style.width.px]=327>
  <input matInput placeholder="Template Name" value="{{templateName}}">
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: In addition to changing of width, is there a way I can change the height too?

Comment: Depending on what you want to achieve - you can set the `style.height` attribute like above and this will give more room at the bottom for the field "hint" text, but won't change the field itself. you can try to assign height to different contained elements (such as `<input`>) to get different effects, but maybe you just want to set different font metrics? try setting `line-height`.

Comment: It works fine with angular material 10, is there a way to put this in a .scss so I can use it from any form? let's say some like class="comments"

Comment: and for percents, `style.width.%`

Answer (score 16):

The following will make the field `50%` of the `Viewport Width` by using `style="width:50vw"`

```
<mat-form-field style="width:50vw" ...>
   ...
</mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 6):

you can use that css tricks

```css
.mat-form-field{
   width:350px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Using fxLayout you can create a flexbox. For making each element in flexbox to consume full row you should use fxFlexFill. For making an element consuming the remaining space you can use fxFlex.

You can also use fxLayoutGap instead of padding in styles. 
Also if you want the elements to go to the next line when there is no more space you can use fxLayout="row wrap".

Here are some samples of what you were looking for:

```xml
    <form class="new-person-form">
        <h3>full Rows:</h3>
        <mat-card fxLayout="row wrap">
            <mat-form-field fxFlexFill>
                <input matInput placeholder="Name" fxFlex="50">
        </mat-form-field>
        <mat-form-field fxFlexFill>
            <input matInput placeholder="Birthday" fxFlex="25">
        </mat-form-field>
        <mat-checkbox fxFlex="25">Active</mat-checkbox>
      </mat-card>
      <h3>50-25-25:(checkbox consumes same space as Birthday)</h3>
      <mat-card fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start center" fxLayoutGap="15px">
          <mat-form-field fxFlex="50">
              <input matInput placeholder="Name">
          </mat-form-field>
          <mat-form-field fxFlex="25">
              <input matInput placeholder="Birthday">
          </mat-form-field>
          <mat-checkbox fxFlex="25">Active</mat-checkbox>
      </mat-card>
      <h3>50-remaining-required:(Birthday consumes remaining space)</h3>
      <mat-card fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start center" fxLayoutGap="15px">
          <mat-form-field fxFlex="50">
              <input matInput placeholder="Name">
          </mat-form-field>
          <mat-form-field fxFlex>
              <input matInput placeholder="Birthday">
          </mat-form-field>
          <mat-checkbox>Active</mat-checkbox>
      </mat-card>
    </form>
```

I've also created a [working example in stack blitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/flex-layout-angular-material-qzzzp5).

Answer (score 2):

Some of the other answers have already sort of suggested this, but the key for me was to set the width on the `mat-form-field` instead of on the `input` element. When I tried to set the `input` element's `width` property (or use CSS `width` on the `input` element) it had no effect at all.

Comment: input width only has effect if (only for type="image")
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_width.asp

Answer (score 2):

Add a class `mat-form-field` in order to decrease width of `mat-input`

```html
<mat-form-field class="reduce-width">
   <mat-label>Label</mat-label>
     <input required matInput type="text"[formControl]="controlName">
</mat-form-field>
```

```css
.reduce-width {
  width: 256px;
  margin-left: 17px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Forcing the styles should do the trick as

```
.mat-input-wrapper{
  width:400px !important;
}
```

OR

```
<mat-form-field style="width:400px !important" ...>
   ...
</mat-form-field>
```

Try adding a class if you want to handle not all the input fields on the page.